# Etymologie und heutige Bedeutung von "bräsig"

Tags: etymology

Ein wohl aus dem Norden Deutschlands stammendes Adjektiv ist *bräsig*. Es begegnet mir immer wieder in Zeitungstexten. Duden Herkunftswörterbuch, Kluge und Deutsches Wörterbuch kennen das Wort nicht. Der Online-Duden bemerkt, daß das Wort aus dem Niederdeutschen komme und ursprünglich *kräftig, wohlgenährt* bedeute.

Die heutige Bedeutung wird angegeben als:

> schwerfällig, ohne Schwung; altmodisch, nicht mehr zeitgemäß ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/braesig))
>   nicht imstande, willens, sich auf jmdn., etw. einzustellen; dickfellig (Duden Universalwörterbuch)

Das scheint mir ein ziemlicher Mischmasch an Bedeutungen, als ob die Wörterbuchmacher sich selber unsicher gewesen wären.

Beispiele aus einer eben durchgeführten Suche bei Google News:

> Assauer mag nicht so breit und nicht so bräsig gewesen sein, erst recht nicht kriminell wie Kampmann, aber ansonsten sind beide Brüder im Geiste.
>
> Man kann sich bräsig über das von der EU verordnete Verbot von Artikeln wie Plastikgabeln echauffieren und deren Gebrauch als zuvorderst zu verteidigendes Freiheitsrecht bezeichnen. Vernünftig ist das nicht.
>
> Der rot-rot-grüne Senat verwaltet die Metropole bräsig und provinziell.
>
> Die deutsche Nationalelf hat den Anschluss an die Spitze verpasst, agiert längst nicht mehr auf der Höhe der Zeit: Ohne Tempo, ohne Idee, ohne Mut, ja fast bräsig spulten die Akteure ihren Stiefel herunter.
>
> Zurück in Deutschland zeigte er großes Interesse an den stets zur Unzeit gurrenden Tauben, die bräsig auf dem Dach hockten, „gurr-gurr“.
>
> Und spätestens an dieser Stelle degeneriert die bräsige Faktenignoranz zur menschlichen Ungeheuerlichkeit.

1) Kennt jemand eine Quelle zur Etymologie des Wortes?

2) Was bedeutet das Wort im heutigen Gebrauch?

Comment: Es erinnert mich sofort an [Brast](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Brast), wohl häufig in der Phrase *im Brast* (bei der Arbeit, unter Druck, im Schwung?). Auf den ersten Blick wohl nicht hierher gehört *Wrase[n-Wasser]*; Der Vergleich drängtbsich mir aber auf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/braesig) liefert zwei mögliche heutige Bedeutungen im Hochdeutsch:

> 1. schwerfällig, ohne Schwung
> 2. altmodisch, nicht mehr zeitgemäß

Das Wort stammt ursprünglich aus dem Niederdeutschen (Platt) und dort haben sich noch etwas [andere Bedeutungen](https://www.ndr.de/kultur/norddeutsche_sprache/plattdeutsch/woerterbuch101_abc-B.html) gehalten:

> - *bräsig* (Hamburg): träge, behäbig, phlegmatisch, langsam im Denken
> - *breesig / breesich* (Husum / Stapelholm): dumm / dümmlich

Es gab mal einen schönen Artikel von [Reinhard Goltz](https://www.welt.de/print/die_welt/hamburg/article108126709/braesig.html), in dem er schreibt:

> Offenbar handelt es sich um **Ableitungen von brusen bzw. dem hochdeutschen brausen**. In der norddeutschen Umgangssprache nimmt bräsig einen festen Platz ein - allerdings nur in der Bedeutung "phlegmatisch, behäbig". Hervorgegangen ist diese Form aus dem plattdeutschen bräsig, und zwar verstanden als "gesund, wohlgenährt.

Diese Auffassung konnte ich auch in einem älteren Wörterbuch [Berlinische regesten von 949 bis 1550](https://books.google.de/books?id=yZkOAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA536&ots=5AptHfT_jf&dq=br%C3%A4sig%20%22brausen%22&pg=PA536#v=onepage&q=br%C3%A4sig&f=false) von Eduard Fidicin aus dem Jahr 1837 finden:

[image]

Demnach hatte *bräsig* seinen Ursprung in der Bierbrauerei, wo es zusammen mit *brauen* und *brausen* wohl aus dem lateinischen *Brasium, braxare* hergeleitet wurde.

Comment: Das ist eine sehr schöne Spurensuche. Gerne stelle ich mir *bräsig* als hergeleitet von *brasium* (Malz) vor. Jedoch: wenn es *berauschend* heißen soll, wie passt das mit den Verwendungen zusammen, die in der Eingangsfrage so schön aufgelistet sind. All dies ist ja nicht berauschend, eher dröge. Huch. Wo kommt nun das Wort *dröge* her? Doch nicht von einer Droge? Am Ende ist *bräsig* einer, der vor lauter Biersaufen müde auf dem Stuhl sitzt und sich nicht mehr rührt?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ja, das würde zu dem Kollegen passen, der laut eigener Aussage häufig *im Brast* war, obwohl er wohl was anderes meinte, doch dem Bier zugeneigt. Naja

Comment: @Takkat wenn ich das richtig lese kommt "davon das lateinische Zeitwort `braxare`" also ein neulateinisches Modewort? [Brasium](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brasium) ist ebenfalls "Anglo-Latin)", nicht klassisch, eventuell Keltischen Ursprungs. Herkunftsangaben aus dem 17Jh. sind eher nicht vertrauenswürdig.

Answer (score 0):

Offensichtlich sind Fritz Reuter, sein Roman *Ut mine Stromtid*, die Verfilmung mit dem Titel *Onkel Bräsig* sowie die gleichnamige Fernsehserie des NDR an dir vorbeigegangen. Okay, 1864, 1936 und 1978-80: alles Arche Noah :-)), und zum Kanon gehört Reuter nicht.  -  In der AGB steht übrigens ein *Onkel Bräsig* mit Lokalbezug. Für den Fall, dass.